# How can I correctly convert into number these string object retrieved from input tag of a form by this JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, javascript-objects

I am pretty new in JavaScript and JQuery and I am having a strange behavior with a simple mathematical sum into a JQuery function that retrieve numbers from some input field inside a JSP page (I can't put a JSFiddle because the values are take from jsp model object)

So, this is my JQuery function:

```
$("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").bind('change keyup', function() {

        console.log("VALUE CHANGED !!!");

        var ulterioreSaldo = $("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").val();     // Non ha separatori di migliaia o di decimanli quindi non devo eseguire replace

        var saldo = $("#saldo").val().replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '').replace(",","."); 
        var anticipo = $("#anticipo").val().replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '').replace(",","."); 

        var totalePagamento = ulterioreSaldo + saldo + anticipo;

        console.log("ulterioreSaldo: " + ulterioreSaldo );
        console.log("ulterioreSaldo type: " + typeof ulterioreSaldo);   

        console.log("saldo: " + saldo);
        console.log("saldo type: " + typeof saldo); 

        console.log("anticipo: " + anticipo);
        console.log("anticipo type: " + typeof anticipo); 

        console.log("totalePagamento: " + totalePagamento);
        console.log("totalePagamento type: " + typeof totalePagamento);   

    });
```

that retrieve and sum 3 values obtained from 3 differents input fields.

So for the values retrieved from the input tags having **id="saldo"** and **id="anticipo"** I apply a replace with 2 regex because these are strings that represent formatted number so before sum I have to obtain a plain number.

The problem is that when I perform the sum of these values by this line:

```
var totalePagamento = ulterioreSaldo + saldo + anticipo;
```

I obtain this wrong outout related to the sum: **totalePagamento: 0.010.004499.48**, this is the entire log into the FireBug Console.

```
VALUE CHANGED !!!
ulterioreSaldo: 0.01
ulterioreSaldo type: string
saldo: 0.00
saldo type: string
anticipo: 4499.48
anticipo type: string
totalePagamento: 0.010.004499.48
totalePagamento type: string
```

As you can see I have also printed the type of the retrieved objects and seems that are String and not Number so when I use the **+** operator these values are concatenated and not summed.

How can I correctly converts these values into Number and sum it?

Comment: Try initializing the variables as number objects, e.g.:
`var ulterioreSaldo = new Number($("#variazioneUlterioreSaldoInput").val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parseFloat() to sum the values

```
var totalePagamento = parseFloat(ulterioreSaldo) + parseFloat(saldo) + parseFloat(anticipo);
totalePagamento = totalePagamento.toFixed(2); //it will set floating point to 2 values e.g. 40.22
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are adding decimal numbers try using parseFloat method:

```
var totalePagamento = parseFloat(ulterioreSaldo) + parseFloat(saldo) + parseFloat(anticipo);
```

And if you want only 2 digits after decimal use:

```
totalePagamento.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `parseFloat()` function to convert string into numbers. The `parseFloat()` function parses a string argument and returns a floating point number.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ulterioreSaldo = "0.01";
var saldo = "0.0";
var anticipo = "4499.48";
var sum = parseFloat(ulterioreSaldo) + parseFloat(saldo) + parseFloat(anticipo);
alert(sum);
});
```

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0r9ptmsr/4/) for the same.